# Meteor Change event based on the value of first selection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this change event and i want to display the value of children based on the value of enrollmentId both are select, the change event is actually works on the console i can see the id of the enrollmentId but on the children option, all children is being passed.

```
  'change select[name=enrollmentId]': function(event, template) {
    var enrollmentId = $(event.target).val();
    console.log(enrollmentId);
    template.$('select[name=childrenId]').val(enrollmentId);
  },
```

the enrollmentId is actually the father so if the user select the father, only his children will appear on the dropdown.

Any help would deeply appreciated.

Thanks,

**Edit**: here's my schema:

`enrollmentId: orion.attribute('hasOne', {
    label: "Principal Name",
    autoform: {
      afFormGroup: {
        'formgroup-class': 'col-xs-6 col-sm-4'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    collection: Enrollments,
    titleField: 'fullName',
    additionalFields:['_id'],
    publicationName: 'enrolledClaim',
    filter: function(userId) {
      var user = Meteor.users.findOne({"_id": userId},{fields: {profile: 1}});
      if ( Roles.userHasRole(userId, "admin") ) {
        // console.log( "Hello Admin" );
        return {};
      } else if ( Roles.userHasRole(userId, 'HQ') ) {
        // console.log( "Hello HQ" );
        return { company: user.profile.company };
      } else if ( Roles.userHasRole(userId, 'Branch') ) {
        // console.log( "Hello Branch" );
        return { createdBy: userId };
      } else if ( Roles.userHasRole(userId, 'insurer') ) {
        // console.log( "Hello Insurer" );
        return {};
      }
    }
  }),
childrenId: orion.attribute('hasMany', {
      label: "Dependent-Children",
      optional: true,
      autoform: {
        afFormGroup: {
          'formgroup-class': 'col-xs-6 col-sm-4'
        }
      },
    },
    {
      collection: Enrollments,
      titleField: 'children.name',
      additionalFields:['children.name'],
      pluralName: 'children',
      publicationName: 'childrenClaim',
      filter: function(userId) {
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({"_id": userId},{fields: {profile: 1}});
        if ( Roles.userHasRole(userId, "admin" ) ) {
          return {};
        } else if ( Roles.userHasRole(userId, 'HQ' ) ) {
          return { company: user.profile.company };
        } else if ( Roles.userHasRole(userId, 'Branch' ) ) {
          return { createdBy: userId };
        } else if ( Roles.userHasRole(userId, 'insurer' ) ) {
          return "No Data";
        }
      }
    }),`

The filter block is use to filter the field based on user profile.
I guess i have to search for other workaround.

Thanks again @ejb for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to dynamically change the options available in your `childrenId` dropdown based on the `enrollmentId` selected.

I haven't seen all of your code but you will have to do something like this:

```
var selectedEnrollmentId = new ReactiveVar();

Template.myForm.events({
    'change select[name=enrollmentId]': function(event, template) {
        selectedEnrollmentId.set($(event.target).val());
    }
});

Template.myForm.helpers({
    childrenOptions: function() {
        return Children.find({enrollmentId: selectedEnrollmentId.get()});
    }
});
```

Then in your `myForm` template you can loop over `childrenOptions` and it will update dynamically.

Note, this code is untested.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @ejb for this.

Comment: Thanks @ejb for this.

But the problem is in my template, i have a quickfield block 
`{{> afQuickField name="childrenId" }}` and this field is coming from orion attribute `hasMany` relationship from other collection. 

I've already raised this issue on their [repo](https://github.com/orionjs/orion/issues/368), currently, the behavior of the relationship is passing the fields from all the documents which is not ideal for all situations. I guess i have to look for another workaround for this.